# SwiftUI Sheet view does not appear when going back previous view with NavigationView

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigation

I have NavigationLink that leads its own view using NavigationView with button that display sheetView.

After moving to the destination view and displaying the sheetView, go back previous view, then the sheetView will not appear even though you tap the button.

If you move to the destination view again, the sheet will appear without tapping the button.

What am I doing wrong?

```
struct MainView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            NavigationView {
                DestinationView()
                    .navigationTitle("Home")
                    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            }
            AddButton()
        }
    }
}

struct DestinationView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var model : Model

    var body: some View {
        List {
            
            NavigationLink(destination:
                            DestinationView().navigationTitle("Test")) {
                Text("Go to Next View")
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $model.isShowingSheet) {
            Text("SheetView")
        }
    }
}

struct AddButton: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var model : Model
    
    var body: some View {
        
            Button(action: {
                model.isShowingSheet = true
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                    .imageScale(.large)
            }
    }
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isShowingSheet: Bool = false
}
```

I prefer not to add the sheetView to MainView or AddButton.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't see the `sheet` when you go back and tap the button, is because
it gets presented in the other view, since you use the **same**
`model.isShowingSheet` variable everywhere.

You could try a different approach, where each `DestinationView` controls its
**own** independent `isShowingSheet` state and you move the `ZStack` to it.

Example code:

```
struct MainView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            DestinationView()
                .navigationTitle("Home")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
 
}

struct DestinationView: View {
    @State private var isShowingSheet: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView().navigationTitle("Test")) {
                    Text("Go to Next View")
                }
            }
            Button(action: {
                isShowingSheet = true
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                    .imageScale(.large)
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet) {
            Text("SheetView")
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-1:

if you really want to use a separate `AddButton`, then you can do this:

```
struct DestinationView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model

    @State private var isShowingSheet: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView().navigationTitle("Test")) {
                    Text("Go to Next View")
                }
            }
            AddButton(isShowingSheet: $isShowingSheet) // <--- here
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet) {
            Text("SheetView")
        }
    }
}

struct AddButton: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model

    @Binding var isShowingSheet: Bool  // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            isShowingSheet = true
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                .imageScale(.large)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your rapid response. 

It works correctly with code you presented. 
However, I would rather not use the this way because button-view also flows when moving to next destination view and the animation is not good.
I would like the button to remain fixed at all times.

Are there any other approaches?

Answer (score 0):

It works if you move the sheet to the parent `ZStack` in `MainView`:

```swift
struct MainView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var model : Model

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // content as before
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $model.isShowingSheet) {
            Text("SheetView")
        }
    }
}

struct DestinationView: View {

    var body: some View {
        List {
            // content as before
        }
        // no sheet here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I  know it works but I prefer not to add the sheetView to MainView or AddButton.